# Joining two dataframes in scala with a column which are not having exact values

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I tried to merge two dataframes with respect to a column which are not having exact same values.

Below given is DF1

```
+--------+-----+------+
| NUM_ID | TIME|SG1_V |
+--------+-----+------+
|XXXXX01 |1001 |79.0  |
|XXXXX01 |1005 |88.0  |
|XXXXX01 |1010 |99.0  |
|XXXXX01 |1015 |null  |
|XXXXX01 |1020 |100.0 |
|XXXXX02 |1001 |81.0  |
|XXXXX02 |1010 |91.0  |
|XXXXX02 |1050 |93.0  |
|XXXXX02 |1060 |93.0  |
|XXXXX02 |1070 |93.0  |
+--------+-----+------+
```

Below is DF2

```
+---------+-----+------+
| NUM_ID  | TIME|SG2_V |
+---------+-----+------+
|XXXXX01  |1001 |  99.0|
|XXXXX01  |1003 |  22.0|
|XXXXX01  |1007 |  85.0|
|XXXXX01  |1011 |  1.0 |

|XXXXX02  |1001 |  22.0|
|XXXXX02  |1009 |  85.0|
|XXXXX02  |1048 |  1.0 |
|XXXXX02  |1052 |  99.0|
+---------+-----+------+
```

I have to join these two DF on columns NUM_ID, which should be exactly same and on column TIME which may/may not be exact value.

The **TIME** in DF2 may/may not contain exact value as in the DF1. If the value is not exact then, I have to join with the highest nearest value available (ie - column value in DF2 should be =< Exact Value in DF1).

It will be more clear after looking at the expected output shown below.

```
+--------+-----+------+-----+------+
| NUM_ID | TIME|SG1_V | TIME|SG2_V |
+--------+-----+------+-----+------+
|XXXXX01 |1001 |79.0  |1001 |  99.0|
|XXXXX01 |1005 |88.0  |1003 |  22.0|
|XXXXX01 |1010 |99.0  |1007 |  85.0|
|XXXXX01 |1015 |null  |1011 |  1.0 |
|XXXXX01 |1020 |100.0 |1011 |  1.0 |

|XXXXX02 |1001 |81.0  |1001 |  22.0|
|XXXXX02 |1010 |91.0  |1009 |  85.0|
|XXXXX02 |1050 |93.0  |1048 |  1.0 |
|XXXXX02 |1060 |93.0  |1052 |  99.0|
|XXXXX02 |1070 |93.0  |1052 |  99.0|
+--------+-----+------+-----+------+
```

For NUM_ID XXXXX01, TIME(1005) in DF1 is not available in DF2, so it took nearest value (1003) which is smaller than 1005.

How to join in such a way that if exact value is not available, then join with nearest value.

Appreciate any leads.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way to do it is by using one of Spark's [Window functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@window), row_number() or rank():

```
scala> spark.sql("""
     |   SELECT * FROM (
     |     SELECT *,
     |       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY df1.NUM_ID, df1.TIME ORDER BY (df1.TIME - df2.TIME)) rno
     |     FROM df1 JOIN df2 
     |     ON df2.NUM_ID = df1.NUM_ID AND 
     |        df2.TIME  <= df1.TIME
     |   ) T
     | WHERE T.rno = 1
     |""").show()
+-------+----+-----+-------+----+-----+---+
| NUM_ID|TIME|SG1_V| NUM_ID|TIME|SG2_V|rno|
+-------+----+-----+-------+----+-----+---+
|XXXXX01|1001| 79.0|XXXXX01|1001| 99.0|  1|
|XXXXX01|1005| 88.0|XXXXX01|1003| 22.0|  1|
|XXXXX01|1010| 99.0|XXXXX01|1007| 85.0|  1|
|XXXXX01|1015| null|XXXXX01|1011|  1.0|  1|
|XXXXX01|1020|100.0|XXXXX01|1011|  1.0|  1|
|XXXXX02|1001| 81.0|XXXXX02|1001| 22.0|  1|
|XXXXX02|1010| 91.0|XXXXX02|1009| 85.0|  1|
+-------+----+-----+-------+----+-----+---+

scala>
```

Comment: @mazaneicha- Since there are two columns with name NUM_ID and TIME, how will I alias different name and select only few columns from this result? I tried doing aliasing but ended up with error ```org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'NUM_ID' is ambiguous, could be: T.NUM_ID, T.NUM_ID;```

Comment: Using a list of columns in projection instead of `*` should work, no? Like `SELECT df1.NUM_ID as NUM_ID1, df2.NUM_ID as NUM_ID2, ... FROM df1 JOIN df2 ...`.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to join by two field using and specific interval for one of them you can do something like:

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.when

  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[1]").getOrCreate()

  val df1 : DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Row("XXXXX01",1001,79.0),
    Row("XXXXX01",1005,88.0),
    Row("XXXXX01",1010,99.0),
    Row("XXXXX01",1015, null),
    Row("XXXXX01",1020,100.0),
    Row("XXXXX02",1001,81.0))),
    StructType(Seq(StructField("NUM_ID", StringType, false), StructField("TIME", IntegerType, false), StructField("SG1_V", DoubleType, true))))

  val df2 : DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Row("XXXXX01",1001,79.0),
    Row("XXXXX01",1001, 99.0),
    Row("XXXXX01",1003, 22.0),
    Row("XXXXX01",1007, 85.1),
    Row("XXXXX01",1011, 1.0),
    Row("XXXXX02",1001,22.0))),
    StructType(Seq(StructField("NUM_ID", StringType, false), StructField("TIME", IntegerType, false), StructField("SG1_V", DoubleType, false))))

  val interval : Int = 10

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    df1.join(df2, ((df1("TIME")) - df2("TIME") > lit(interval)) && df1("NUM_ID") === df2("NUM_ID")).show()
  }
```

It gives as result:

```
+-------+----+-----+-------+----+-----+
| NUM_ID|TIME|SG1_V| NUM_ID|TIME|SG1_V|
+-------+----+-----+-------+----+-----+
|XXXXX01|1015| null|XXXXX01|1001| 79.0|
|XXXXX01|1015| null|XXXXX01|1001| 99.0|
|XXXXX01|1015| null|XXXXX01|1003| 22.0|
|XXXXX01|1020|100.0|XXXXX01|1001| 79.0|
|XXXXX01|1020|100.0|XXXXX01|1001| 99.0|
|XXXXX01|1020|100.0|XXXXX01|1003| 22.0|
|XXXXX01|1020|100.0|XXXXX01|1007| 85.1|
+-------+----+-----+-------+----+-----+
```

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44-The base TIME column which is considered is of DF1. All the values in DF1 TIME column should be there in the resulting DF. Here in the above solution the times, 1005, 1010 are missing???

Comment: For that you can use a left_join and to get only from the right side the rows that match the two fields join function. If you need an example I can update the answer

Answer (score 0):

The above solution is joining the dataframes after saving it into hive table.

I tried to join two dataframes without saving into hive table by applying the same logic and it is as shown below.

```
val finalSignals = finalABC.as("df1").join(finalXYZ.as("df2"), $"df1.NUM_ID" === $"df2.NUM_ID" && $"df2.TIME"  <= $"df1.TIME", "left").withColumn("rno", row_number.over(Window.partitionBy($"df1.NUM_ID", $"df1.TIME").orderBy($"df1.TIME" - $"df2.TIME"))).select(col("df1.NUM_ID").as("NUM_ID"),col("df1.TIME"),col("df2.NUM_ID").as("NUM_ID2"),col("df1.TIME").as("TIME2"),
col("rno")).filter("rno == 1")
```

Is this equivalent to the above provided solution

```
spark.sql("""
     |   SELECT * FROM (
     |     SELECT *,
     |       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY df1.NUM_ID, df1.TIME ORDER BY (df1.TIME - df2.TIME)) rno
     |     FROM df1 JOIN df2 
     |     ON df2.NUM_ID = df1.NUM_ID AND 
     |        df2.TIME  <= df1.TIME
     |   ) T
     | WHERE T.rno = 1
     |""")
```

Comment: @mazaneicha-please check this